# Обьяснит простое уровнение на C#

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a = 3;
            int b = 5;
            int c = 40;
            int d = c-- - b * a;
            Console.WriteLine($"a={a}  b={b}  c={c}  d={d}");

        }
    }
}
```

Я не очень понимаю данный код. Сначала идёт 40-1=39 затем 5*3=15 и 39-15=24 тогда вопрос как получается 25? Что я упустил прошу обьяснить глупому

Comment: `c--` означает, что сначала посчитается значение всего выражения, а потом уже из с уменьшится на единицу. То есть сначала будет `d=40-5*3`, а потом уже `c=c-1`. То, что вы описываете, будет выглядеть как `int d = --c - b * a`

Comment: Вы могли бы написать это как ответ и я засчитал бы решением моего вопроса. Вы мне очень помогли

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`c--` означает, что сначала посчитается значение всего выражения, а потом уже из с уменьшится на единицу. То есть сначала будет

```
d=40-5*3,
```

а потом уже

```
c=c-1.
```

То, что вы описываете, будет выглядеть как

```
int d = --c - b * a
```